# If I require any file in my own wordpress plugin, will there be a security breach?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is a question about wordpress plugin security.
Here is my code. I require a PHP file but I think it is not secure

```
public function file_include() {
    $files = scandir(DRUBO_CORE_WDGT_DIR);
    foreach ($files as $value) {
        if (!in_array(trim($value), ['.', '..'])) {
          require DRUBO_CORE_WDGT_DIR .'/'.$value;
        }   
    }
}

public function shortcodes_basename(){
    $files = scandir(DRUBO_SHORTCODE_DIR);
    foreach ($files as $value) {
        if (!in_array(trim($value), ['.', '..'])) {
          $basename[] =  basename($value , '.php'); 
        }   
    }
    return $basename ;
}

public function shortcodes_include(){
    $basename = $this->shortcodes_basename();
    foreach ($basename as $value) {
        require DRUBO_SHORTCODE_DIR .'/'.$value.'.php'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it is not secure? Please persuade us that you have done some research.

Comment: Because  i search all file by using scandir function ,, 
 then i require all file . i think if any one ( heacker ) put his own file   at DRUBO_CORE_WDGT_DIR  then his scripts will start running  ,,


$files = scandir(DRUBO_CORE_WDGT_DIR); 

public function file_include() {
    $files = scandir(DRUBO_CORE_WDGT_DIR);
    foreach ($files as $value) {
        if (!in_array(trim($value), ['.', '..'])) {
          require DRUBO_CORE_WDGT_DIR .'/'.$value;
        }   
    }
}

Comment: Because  i search all file by using scandir function ,, 
 then i require all file . i think if any one ( heacker ) put his own file   at DRUBO_CORE_WDGT_DIR  then his scripts will start running  ,,

Comment: scandir(DRUBO_CORE_WDGT_DIR); print all file name . then          
  require DRUBO_SHORTCODE_DIR .'/'.$value.'.php';